# i8kmon reporting no temperature on Dell Inspirion 2310 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dell, cpu, fan, temperature

My problem is that I have a Dell Inspirion 2310 with Ubuntu 18.04 and I am struggling with installing i8kmon correctly.
When executing i8kmon with my config file, the fan control does not seem to work. I am using s-tui to stress the cpu and my settings have no effect whatsoever.

/etc/i8kmon.conf:

```
# Sample i8kmon configuration file (/etc/i8kmon.conf, ~/.i8kmon).
# External program to control the fans
set config(i8kfan)  /usr/bin/i8kfan
# Run as daemon, override with --daemon option
set config(daemon) 0
# Automatic fan control, override with --auto option
set config(auto) 1
set config(nouserconfig) 1
# Applet geometry, override with --geometry option
set config(geometry)    {48x48}
# Report status on stdout, override with --verbose option
set config(verbose) 1
# Status check timeout (seconds), override with --timeout option
set config(timeout) 5
# Temperature display unit (C/F), override with --unit option
set config(unit)    C
# Temperature threshold at which the temperature is displayed in red
set config(t_high)  90
# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
# These were tested on the I8000. If you have a different Dell laptop model
# you should check the BIOS temperature monitoring and set the appropriate
# thresholds here. In doubt start with low values and gradually rise them
# until the fans are not always on when the cpu is idle.
set config(0) {{1 0} -1 66 -1 60}
set config(1) {{1 1} 55 70 50 70}
set config(2) {{2 2} 60 80 60 80}
set config(3) {{2 2} 70 128 70 128}
# end of file
```

I am beginning to believe that i8kmon does not get a correct temperature reading:

```
i8kctl temp
```

reports -1 which means that it cannot read the temperature
i8kfan is working correctly, allowing me to set the speed of both fans accordingly

when reading /proc/i8k, I am receiving the following values

```
1.0 A04 BCMXXXX -22 1 1 5818 1670 -1 -22
```

The output of

sensors

```
radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +56.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan:   1670 RPM
Motherboard Fan: 5625 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +42.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 2:       +42.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

How can I get i8kmon to get the correct temperature reading?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten i8kmon to work but resolved the issue by simply using fancontrol.

Comment: I would delete packages and use `tlp` only.